# One taxonomy template for all categories?

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I'm looking at the Codex about template hierarchy. However, I have a custom post type with many categories from a custom taxonomy I created also.

This post type allows users to add new categories to their posts. I read in the codex that I can create a `taxonomy-{taxonomy-name}.php` template file for each of my taxonomies. What I am wondering is if I can create one template file to "catch" all of the CPT's categories.

Comment: Your question is a bit difficult to follow, because it reads as if *category* and *taxonomy* are interchangeable. Just for clarity: what all *taxonomies* are registered for your CPT? Regarding *categories*, which is a specific *taxonomy*: did you add post-type support for the *category* taxonomy? And which *taxonomy* do you wish to display for this particular template file?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's worth clarifying a bit of terminology first:

- Taxonomy - a set of related terms
- Term - an entry (I want to just say "term") in a taxonomy
- Categories - a taxonomy that's in the default WordPress
- Tags - a taxonomy that's in the default WordPress
- Category - a term in the Categories taxonomy
- Tag - a term in the Tags taxonomy
- Custom taxonomy - a non-default taxonomy in WordPress

So the `taxonomy-{taxonomy-name}.php` template targets all terms in a specific taxonomy. `taxonomy-{taxonomy-name}-{term}.php` targets a specific *term* in a taxonomy.

I'd encourage you to take a look at the [Template Hierarchy flow chart](http://codex.wordpress.org/File%3aTemplate_Hierarchy.png?utm_source=wordpress-modguide) from the Codex. From what you describe it sounds like you either need to use `archive.php` that affects all archives (assuming you haven't specified a more-specific template) or `taxonomy.php` which targets all Custom Taxonomy archives (so not Categories or Tags).